# Logon failed (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'

Tags: python, azure, connection

I have big issues to connect to the sql sever with python 3.8. I wonder if I need to downgrade to 3.7 python and if there is something else I am doing wrong?

HERE IS MY CODE AND ERROR MESSAGE:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus \
('Driver={SQL 
Server};Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433; 
Database=GroceryDB;Uid=xxxxx;Pwd= 
{xxxx};Encrypt=no;Connection Timeout=30;')

conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = 
sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(conn_str,echo=False,pool_pre_ 
ping=True)
```

Logon failed (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxx'.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can reinstall odbc driver as administrator, or use another pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NEWEST

You can follow the document([Open the ODBC Data Source Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/open-the-odbc-data-source-administrator?view=sql-server-ver15)) to check the odbc driver whether installed successfully.

[image]

## PRIVIOUS

Below code works for me.

```
from urllib import parse
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

params = parse.quote_plus \
(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yoursqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=sasasa;Pwd={pwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')

conn_str="mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params)

engine= create_engine (conn_str,echo=True)

connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select 1+1 as res")
for row in result:
print("res:", row['res'])
connection.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi!
I tried exactly same code you shared with my own credientials but I still get this error... 
I do not know if the error is my driver or something else.

 [SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0);

Comment: @YaxumCedeno I believe you must test in your local machine,right?

Comment: @YaxumCedeno You should install driver in your local machine.

Comment: @YaxumCedeno If you deploy your code as webjobs or others, the error will disappear.

Comment: I downloaded the driver from the microsoft website with the version 17 with succes. But how do I check if it is OK?

Comment: I want to be able to run the code on my local machine. Do you have any good link for the webjobs? I am not familier with this word and have only worked on my local machine :/

Comment: @YaxumCedeno It’s very hard to say for me right now, because I don’t have lab top now. Can you deploy it as webjob or function, print logs to check. It must the driver issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225523/discussion-between-yaxum-cedeno-and-jason-pan).